# nginx default configuration on amazon cloud

Tags: emacs, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have setup up a cloud and installed nginx on it. I can start and stop nginx through msysgit.
However I want to change the configuration file and am using the following command
`emacs /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

However the file is read only  and I can't `chmod` it. Any ideas how I can make it writable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing your command to `sudo emacs /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`